# When i try to read file from s3 bucket error occurs, what is the problem?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.csv.
: java.io.IOException: The s3n:// client to Amazon S3 is no longer available: please migrate to the s3a:// client
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.initialize(NativeS3FileSystem.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:619)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anyone help me about this error type? 
My codes like this:

```
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", secretAccessKey)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using pr passing  AWS S3 bucket URL with prefix as `s3://` or `s3n://` then replace it with `s3a://` because Spark uses `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` for S3 communications and you also might have to include `hadoop-aws 2.7.1 JAR` on to your classpath

Comment: in jupyter notebook my code like this:spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", secretAccessKey) , which config files will i replace it?

Comment: i'd recommend looking at the docs https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html